Python file.save saves empty file
I retrieve files from a frontend upload, and convert an hash over the file this way:
blob_file = convert_to_blob(file)

with this function:
def convert_to_blob(file: file_storage.FileStorage) -> bytes:
    os_path = os.path.join(config('UPLOAD_CONVERT'), "convert.pdf")
    file.save(os_path)
    # Convert digital data to binary format
    with open(os_path, 'rb') as file:
        blobData = file.read()
    return blobData

this works fine and the file is saved as expected.
After that I save the file a second time, but with the hash as name in the folder intendend for the file:
   if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        # first, convert the file as blob, so we can build a hash over the blob
        blob_file = convert_to_blob(file)
        hash_ = hashlib.md5(blob_file).hexdigest()

        # save file local
        file_path = f"{config('UPLOAD_FOLDER')}/{request.form['mandant']}"
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            os.makedirs(file_path)

        os_path = os.path.join(f"{file_path}/{hash_}.pdf")
        file.save(os_path)

But for some reason, the second time around the file won't properly save.
It's always empty.
I've tried to save the file in different folders and without the hash-building stuff before, but no luck.
Can someone explain what's happening here?
Edit:
file type -> <class 'werkzeug.datastructures.file_storage.FileStorage'>
Edit2:
Okay, it is because of the file.save, it seems like the file is closed after or something?
Is there a way to avoid that without reopening the file?

Okay, it was indeed the file.save that caused the problem.
I've switched to a function with shutil that copies the file to the destination before I overthink that problem:
def save_file_local(mandant: str, hash_: str) -> str:
    # save file local
    file_path = f"{config('UPLOAD_FOLDER')}/{mandant}"
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        os.makedirs(file_path)
    file_path = os.path.join(f"{file_path}/{hash_}.pdf")
    shutil.copyfile(convert_path, file_path)

    return file_path


To fix this, you can add the 'file.seek(0)' after reading the file to reset the file pointer to the beginning.

Added that after the read, but still no luck. I've tried it without the function also, but that didn't help either

You're right, kinda. It is because of the file.save.  Do you have a suggestion how to keep the file open without reopening the file? (I think the file is closed after saving)
